# Find if element exists in XML column of a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have data serialized to a XML column in a SQL Server table in the form:

```
<Form title="Sample Data">
  <MyProperty>1234</MyProperty>
  <Employee>
     <MyProperty>1234</MyProperty>
  </Employee>
</Form>
```

The element `MyProperty` can either be at the root level, or a child element under `<Employee>`.

What I need is a SQL script that:

1. Checks to see if `MyProperty` exists at the root level of the XML (I don't care about the child version of it)
2. If it doesn't exist, insert the record at the root level.

The value of `MyProperty` will have been previously calculated and I plan to place it into a temp table, along with the PK of the row that has the serialized XML.

Can anyone give some guidance on how to do this?

Comment: One question at a time please, especially when you have no idea where or how to start. What are you trying to achieve first? I assume :  "checks to see if MyProperty exists at the root level of the XML". Read about [`exist()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) method and try to implement it for your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question may be answered by using simple XPATH syntax as shown below.

```
declare @x xml = '<Form title="Sample Data">
  <MyProperty>1234</MyProperty>
  <Employee>
     <MyProperty>1234</MyProperty>
  </Employee>
</Form>';


--does MyProperty exist at the root level?
declare @rootlevelvalue nvarchar(max) = (select T.c.value('(MyProperty)[1]','nvarchar(max)') from @x.nodes('/Form') T(c));
if @rootlevelvalue is not null
begin
  print 'yes, it exists at the root level (value = ' + @rootlevelvalue + ')';
end
else
begin
  print 'no, it does not exist at the root level'
end
```

And the second question can be answered with XPATH's *insert* syntax.

```
declare @y xml = '<Form title="Sample Data">
  <Employee>
     <MyProperty>1234</MyProperty>
  </Employee>
</Form>';


--does MyProperty exist at the root level?
declare @rootlevelvalue nvarchar(max) = (select T.c.value('(MyProperty)[1]','nvarchar(max)') from @y.nodes('/Form') T(c));
if @rootlevelvalue is not null
begin
  print 'yes, it exists at the root level (value = ' + @rootlevelvalue + ')';
end
else
begin
  print 'no, it does not exist at the root level';
  set @y.modify('insert <MyProperty>99999</MyProperty>into (/Form)[1]')
  print 'so we added it.';
end
select @y
```

Comment: Thanks, regarding the first part:
I used .exist() to check if the element exists in the XML as suggested by har07.